# What is wrong with my C++ code involving a function calling another function?

Tags: c++, function, loops, fault

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// function prototypes
string boxOfStars(int w, int h);
string lineOfStars(int len);

// function definitions
string lineOfStars(int len) {
    string result = "";
    for (int j=0; j<len; j++) {
        result += "*";
    }
    return result;
}

string boxOfStars(int w, int h) {
    string result_1 = lineOfStars(w);
    for (int i=0; i<h; i++)
        cout << result_1 << endl;

    return 0;
}

int main() {

    int width, length;

    cout << ""Enter a width and length: ";
    cin >> width >> length;
    cout << boxOfStars(width, length);

    return 0;
}
```

The point of this program is to call the `lineOfStars()` function within the `boxOfStars()` function.

When I run the program, I get a "Segmentation fault: 11" error.

```
Enter a width and length: 5 5
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I have tried searching for this all over the internet, but cannot seem to find the issue.

The program runs fine in the terminal, but at the end of each output, I get this error message.

Can someone please explain to me the fault in my code?

Comment: You are returning `0` in your `boxOfStars()`. You have several options: use `cout` inside `boxOfStars()` and make it `void` or compose a string containing lines of stars, return than string and `cout` it inside `main()`.

Comment: In addition to the problems causing the segfault, your `lineOfStars` function should be a lot simpler. Instead of adding to a string in a loop, it's better to just call the `string` constructor which accepts a character and length, as just `return string(len, '*');`.

Comment: @Ryan: This is what a debugger is meant for.  Learn how to use one.  It would have helped you find the segfault.

Answer (score 4):

`boxOfStars()` has a return type of `std::string`, but it is returning `0`, which gets interpreted as a null `char*` pointer.  Passing a null `char*` pointer to the `std::string` constructor is **undefined behavior**.

You probably want `boxOfStars()` to return `void` instead, and not have the `cout << boxOfStars(...)` in your `main()`.

Comment: I think it would be better to return a `string` from `boxOfStars`, and only `cout` in `main`. Either way, returning 0 as a string is bad.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to `cout` the result of `BoxOfStars`, which is 0. The function `BoxOfStars` itself is doing the `cout` for the stars. Seems you have doubled-up code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
string boxOfStars(int w, int h) {
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}
```

you're trying to return `0` and you say it returns a `string`. So the compiler adds a conversion to `string` for you, the same as you wrote this:

```
string boxOfStars(int w, int h) {
    /* ... */
    return (string)0;
}
```

Specifically in this case, `0` is interpreted as a null pointer, and it will call the constructor that creates a `string` from a `const char *`. Trying to access the null pointer (to read the string) causes the segfault. Oops!